# MySQL Local vs. remote performance

Tags: mysql, performance, mariadb

I have a huge problem with **MySQL** and **MariaDB**.

When I execute my query on my local machine, I get a decent performance.If I execute my query on remote server (**Virtual Server with same config and resource**) the performance goes down to about **50%** of what I have on my local machine. I have tried several servers (**Virtual Servers with same config and resource**). I have also tried different client machines.

MariaDB on local machine result:

[image: MariaDB on local machine result]

MariaDB on remote server result:

[image: MariaDB on remote server result]

PLEASE SOMEBODY HELP ME!

Comment: Not really sure what help you expect from us based on a query. Record numbers, different workload, different config, different indexes - these all can result in different performance, but there is nothing in your question that would enable us to narrow down the problem.

Comment: Virtual machines are not the same as bare metal. Are you running both servers with the same hardware? What hypervisor are you using? Do you have exclusive reservation of resources? Does your time include networking roundtrip etc.? You need to provide much more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: How far away is the "remote" server?  That is, what is the 'ping' time?  How big is the result set?  Is it typically 9 rows, like your screen shots, or is it much bigger amounts?  What version of MariaDB?  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of remote virtual machines.

Your local machine is, well, local, so no network latency comes into play. If instead you use a database server on a remote machine, your operations must travel to the remote machine and back again.

Your local machine is dedicated to your use (I presume it's your personal laptop). Your remote database  machine is probably a virtual machine sharing a host  with many other virtual machines. So your database server responds more sluggishly to requests.

It's inconvenient reality.

In a production environment, ordinarily a database server connects to the machine running the queries via a very-low-latency gigabit Ethernet or something similar.

Comment: This makes some sense, but at the same time it does not. If I am running the same query on the server using our app, the result comes back significantly faster (around 10x faster) then when running the app and sending the same query over to the same server. The SQL command and the result set has network latency, but the processing of the data on the server side should be the same, however, it seems it is not.